# How to display the KDE system tray icons on LXDE panel?

Tags: kde, lxde, kde5, panel, tray

With KDE, I sometime need to close/kill KDE (`plasmashell`) to have more available system resources, while doing so I run `lxpanel` on its own to have a minimal panel while KDE Plasma is closed. This does work flawlessly but the system tray.

On the LXDE panel (`lxpanel`) I have added the `system tray` applet and did get the tray to work only when I launch application with the following commands:

```
# is currently KDE even if plasmashell is closed
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXDE
dbus-launch app_using_tray
```

Is there a way to have the currently running tray applications displayed on lxpanel? or is there any alternative that would permit to access to those application while `plasmashell` is closed? How to display the KDE system tray icons when plasmashell is replaced temporarily with LXDE panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**X Tray System:**

On most desktops the tray icon system can be replaced with other system like `stalonetray`, `trayer` or `wmsystemtray` while doing so, the tray system needs to be registered as the used tray system, for KDE details can be found [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=86780) this is why `dbus-launch` and `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` are required when the alternative tray is not the default.

**LXDE Panel With KDE:**

Indeed LXDE panel (`lxpanel`) can be run along with other desktop like KDE... since the purpose here is just to switch to a lighter desktop when the usage require more ressources, the tray problem can be fixed with `plasmawindowed` this will permit to run `org.kde.plasma.systemtray` in a windowed mode in a single instance and thus have the tray system accessible while using `lxpanel`, further more windows rules can be used to arrange it as a panel (without the decoration etc.) this bash script can be used to switch the desktop to a lighter one, and closing it would be done with `ctrl+c`:

```
#!/bin/bash

kill_panel() {
    killall lxpanel
}

trap 'kill_panel' SIGINT

/usr/bin/lxpanel&
plasmawindowed org.kde.plasma.systemtray
```

Additional infos about [system tray](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14555/what-is-the-difference-between-indicators-and-a-system-tray)