# How can add gnome-weather in the bottom panel of lxde?

Tags: lxde, panel

I have installed gnome-weather:

```
sudo apt install gnome-weather
```

`Menu--Accessories--Weather` can launch it.

Is there a way to set it on the bottom panel of lxde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gnome Weather](https://apps.gnome.org/app/org.gnome.Weather/) is an app that is created for [Gnome desktop](https://www.gnome.org/). Gnome desktop does not use system tray icons in its desktop. So Gnome Weather (and other Gnome core apps) will not have system tray icons for now.

If you want an app with a system tray icon you'll need to find some other app that is created for LXDE or similar desktops like Plasma. In that case [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/590519/416910) will be relevant for you.

If you're interested in why Gnome does not have system tray icons, then you can read a [blog post](https://blogs.gnome.org/aday/2017/08/31/status-icons-and-gnome/) about it.